# If someone is abusive in another language (not in English), what to do?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, offensive, english

If someone is abusive in a language that's not English, what to do?

I flagged it as offensive but it got declined...

Comment: Are you sure that it was abuse only? (He mite be praising you :P ) (In anycase that ought to be flagged as *not constructive* if a comment, else edited out)

Comment: @BhargavRao that was not for me he include in code and DN

Comment: Use the "in need of moderator intervention" or "other" flag option and clearly explain what the problem is. Point out that it's offensive and in what language the user is insulting.

Comment: @Bart hmm Thanks. I did as you said

Comment: I also once flagged a comment as offensive that was in another language. I translated it with Google Translate with “Recognize Language”, it was indeed offensive and the flag was helpful…

Comment: Apart from reporting it, you should also teach them its translation in english.

Comment: Uvijek mu mozes opsovati familiju na vlastitom jeziku.

Answer (score 5):

***If the offensive remark is a question or answer***, I'd most likely flag as rude or abusive. I would think that the moderator would be able to use a tool like [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) to see for themselves that the post is rude/abusive. In some cases I may choose to leave a comment under the post as well explaining that it's rude/abusive. If the post just has like one line of little, tiny rude remark to it, so not that rude, and all the other lines are good and are helpful to programming, I would probably just edit that part out.  If it's a really rude/abusive remark but also contains good content I'd probably flag explaining what it means in custom mod message and let the mod handle it how they see fit. If the user has history of leaving bad remarks in posts I'd do custom mod flag giving links to different posts where the user has done this.

***If the offensive remark is a comment***, I'd flag as rude or abusive in most cases and also check some of the user's other comments. If the user appears to have done this multiple times than I'll do a custom moderator flag and provide links to the multiple comments and let mod handle it. If it's just the one time, probably just flag as rude or abusive.

Comment: It would be better for the moderator to flag it 'in need of moderator attention' and write the explanation (with relevant subsection of translation and language identified) of what the trouble is.  You can start 'Rude or Offensive' and then add the explanation.  This applies to questions, answers or comments.